# Oracle Forms 10g or 11g for users with limited vision

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, accessibility, oracleforms

I want to know, how to make Oracle Forms 10g or 11g more accessible to people with disabilities. For starters, is Oracle Forms compatible with web browser zoom level, if not, is there some way to dynamically change size of Forms items? I tried to search in the internet, but there is so little information about that.

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/accessibility/resources/forms-applications-accessibility-1358647.pdf) was the first hit I got from 'oracle forms accessibility'. Or there's [this](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/citizenship/open-computing/accessibility/index.html).

Comment: Unfortunately the [VPAT](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/accessibility/templates/t1616.html) gives little information. Not being a Forms user, I cannot speak on them. If you can provide a demo, i can take a look

Comment: Yesterday I found first link too, Java Access Bridge worth of trying. I am working on demo right now, I write my progress when I reach some results.

Comment: Yes, if you are writing JAVA, the JAB must be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the ClientDPI parameter in webforms.cfg

I've used it to fix form size (you could say "zoom level") on linux and mac clients. It's not user configurable, but you could offer your users several zoom options through the calling url

Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e10240/configure.htm

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8563562
i did not have to install the browser in mention, i used an old mozilla firefox version and looks nice and crispy..ttthe key is the script's terminal.
i changed the clientDPI too to adjunt the size a little.
Oracle Forms runtime 10